# Calculation of reliable digits for one linear system

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, linear-algebra, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

> Example: the linear equation system $Ax=b$ has one approximation $\bar x$ and
>   one exact $x^* \neq 0$ solutions. we also gives: $p>3,   ||x^* - \bar
>  x || \leq 10^{-20} + ||A||  ||A^{-1}|| 10^{-p} ||x^*|| $ which $||A|| 
> ||A^{-1}||=10^{4}$. The reliable digits of $\bar x$ for solutions of
>   this system of equation is $0$.

---

**Question: this example takes from my notes on Numerical Methods Course. anyone may describe it, which calculation reach the author to get $0$?**

> None of these two answers is not help me, I need some detail about
>   this example. how we conclude that this example works?

Comment: Are you sure that you are not using the condition number $\|A\|·\|A^{-1}\|$? And since that is always $\ge1$, the last number should be the more realistic $10^4$? A relative error of $10$ or even $1$ would indeed invalidate the result.

Comment: Sorry this is a typo. I fix it @LutzL thanks for your nice inspection.

Comment: The example is still impossible. By basic norm inequalities, $1=\|I\|=\|A·A^{-1}\|\le\|A\|·\|A^{-1}\|$. And $1\le 10^{-4}$ is always wrong.

Answer (score 2):

In the case of $p=4$ you get
$$
\|x-x^*\|\le 10^{-20}+\|x^*\|
$$
which means that in the worst case, the error is as large as the exact solution. In digits that means that any digit may be wrong.

---

For instance, if $x^*$ were one-dimensional with value $10$, then the possible values for $x$ would range from about $0$ to about $20$, which means that not even the leading digit is certain, even with rounding. In higher-dimensional cases you would get a ball around the exact solution, so for instance $x^*=(10,0)$ allows for $x=(5,-5)$ etc.

Comment: Would you please describe for me your example? what is $||xx-\bar x||$, and $p$ and $||x^*||$ in your example? thanks

Answer (score 1):

Putting aside the remark by @Lutzl that $$1\le \|A\|\|A^{-1}\|$$ and hence there must a typo somewhere in the estimation $10^{-4}$, we can always examine the following case.

Let the true solution of an equation is $ x^*=1$. Let the admissible error be $10^{-n}$. We take an approximate solution $\bar x = 1 - 10^{-2n}$. The error is within acceptable bounds, yet no digits of $\bar x$ and of $x^*$ are the same.

Comment: Would you please describe which typo? is it possible to explain more? in which condition that $\bar x$ and $x^*$ be same?

Comment: @MichleJordan I think that estimate should be $10^4$. The values of $\bar  x$ and $x^*$ are the same only if the admissible error is zero.

Comment: would you please consider this is a typo and $10^4$ is correct, and describe a bit more about your answer?

Comment: @MichleJordan the exact value of $\|A\|\|A^{-1}\|$ is irrelevant for our problem as long as it is superior to $1$. Consider two numbers $1$ and $0.9999999$. The latter number approximates the former one with an arbitrary precision  - just put enough $9$s in decimal digits. Yet these two numbers have no common digits. Therefore, no matter how good your approximation is, you can not guarantee that the approximate solution has common digits with the true solution.

Comment: Now, I understand more, thanks, my last question is if the $10^4$ be correct, your answer is very short :) your answer is so nice for expert man, would you please add more context in your solution to add more learning for beginner like me?  you wrote very understandable, please add more detail for us in your answer to get familiar completely with this type of question. thanks

Comment: I study more, I know waste your time but I have one question, may I ask?